# Best Way to Protect A Desktop From Power Surge/Dirty Power?

Tags: power-supply, power, desktop-computer

What is the best way to protect a computer desktop from a power surge/dirty power? Would a power strip be adequate? (I don't have much space in my desk.)

Answer (score 1):

add a small, tiny UPS to the chain of power. It should help enormously.

Answer (score 1):

best protection can be provided by a good ups which have built in surge protection. But if you have already a ups without this protection then a power strip with surge protector circuitry will be ok.

if you have crt monitor do not connect it to ups.