# How much can power surge damage hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply

I have 2 hdds that started slowly dying (low speed, high response times, high activity time, racking up reallocated sector counts) in a period of week. Can it be because of power surge or faulty PSU? I suppose that power surge would just fry it, may be the problem is with sudden shutdown?

SMART info:

```
01  Raw Read Error Rate                  6    99   88    158946163  OK: Value is normal
03  Spinup Time                          0    94   92            0  OK: Always passes
04  Start/Stop Count                     20   97   97         3218  OK: Value is normal
05  Reallocated Sector Count             36   68   68         1317  OK: Value is normal
07  Seek Error Rate                      30   87   60    562871335  OK: Value is normal
09  Power-On Time Count                  0    58   58        37286  OK: Always passes
0A  Spinup Retry Count                   97   100  100           0  OK: Value is normal
0C  Power Cycle Count                    20   99   99         1588  OK: Value is normal
B7  <vendor-specific>                    0    100  100           0  OK: Always passes
B8  End-to-End Error                     99   100  100           0  OK: Value is normal
BB  Reported Uncorrectable Errors        0    1    1          2610  OK: Always passes
BC  Command Timeout                      0    100  99      1114129  OK: Always passes
BD  High Fly Writes                      0    100  100           0  OK: Always passes
BE  Airflow Temperature                  45   60   45           40  OK: Value is normal
C2  Temperature                          0    40   55           40  OK: Always passes
C3  Hardware ECC Recovered               0    40   22    158946163  OK: Always passes
C5  Current Pending Sector Count         0    100  100          32  OK: Always passes
C6  Offline Uncorrectable Sector Count   0    100  100          32  OK: Always passes
C7  Ultra ATA CRC Error Rate             0    200  200           0  OK: Always passes
F0  Head Flying Hours                    0    100  253       41456  OK: Always passes
F1  Total Host Writes                    0    100  253  1140260453  OK: Always passes
F2  Total Host Reads                     0    100  253   321833633  OK: Always passes
```

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: You may find this interesting to read the answers: http://superuser.com/questions/287709/is-it-bad-to-leave-your-computer-on-during-a-thunderstorm

Comment: Added SMART info, reallocated sector count went from 960 to 1317 in a week. Yet it was working fine yesterday.

Comment: What make/model are the HDs? Some fail much faster than others, see https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-reliability-stats-q1-2016/ [& similar over the past couple of years] for some of the only high-volume client-side published figures

Comment: The older one is seagate ST31000528AS, newer was seagate as well ST1000DM003. The reason I'm worried is 5 year old hdd and 1.5 year old hdd fail together in 7 days.

Comment: Maybe somebody kicked the enclosure!  Why do you even suspect a power surge?  The HDD is not the sole electrical device in a computer.  A power surge would have likely affected other components, especially the PSU.

Comment: I have noticed seagate ST####DM### have never been good drives.  I have had many fail on me <1 year each.  If your PSU 5V or 12V wires were greater than + or - 5% for a long time maybe.  Generally if a surge is large enough to get through the power supply fries everything.

Comment: As written, your question is off-topic because the direct answers would be speculation, which is why it has attracted close votes.  The real question is whether the drive is behaving normally and reliably, or what, if anything, can be done to attempt to restore it to that condition.  Consider editing your question to reframe it.